# Prevent .NET Speech Recognition from hearing/recognizing computer speakers

Tags: c#, audio, speech-recognition

I know this is a long shot, and very difficult, maybe even impossible to do. But I'm going to ask it anyway.

Is there any way to keep .NET's `SpeechRecognitionEngine` (SAPI) from hearing or recognizing the audio coming from computer speakers, without using an external microphone.

An example would be

> Playing a YouTube video, or song, and not of the Recognizer
>   listen to the audio form that video or song Or at least not recognize it as speech

Thanks

Comment: In theory if you have an internal audio source like the YouTube video and want to exclude that from things processed by an internal microphone, you can invert the audio signal from that source and use it to cancel out the same sound picked up via the microphone.  That is how noise cancelling headphones work.  I have no idea whether that is possible with SAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In theory if you have an internal audio source like the YouTube video and want to exclude that from things processed by an internal microphone, you can invert the audio signal from that source and use it to cancel out the same sound picked up via the microphone. That is how noise cancelling headphones work. I have no idea whether that is possible with SAPI  –  Eric J.

While implementing this would take to long for me, this seems like the most do-able and reasonable answer.